# Difference between linear regression in Python (and R) and Stata

Tags: python, stata, linear-regression

I'm porting a Stata model to Python, and seeing different results for Python and Stata for linear regression using the same input data (available @ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8PLy9yAUHvlcTI1SG5sdzdnaWc/view?usp=sharing)

The Stata codes are as below:

```
reg growth time*
predict ghat
predict resid, residuals
```

And result is (first 5 rows):

```
. list growth ghat resid

     +----------------------------------+
     |    growth       ghat       resid |
     |----------------------------------|
  1. | 2.3527029   2.252279    .1004239 |
  2. |  2.377728   2.214551     .163177 |
  3. | 2.3547957   2.177441     .177355 |
  4. | 3.0027488   2.140942    .8618064 |
  5. | 3.0249328    2.10505    .9198825 |
```

In Python, the codes are:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


def linear_regression(df, dep_col, indep_cols):
  lf = LinearRegression(normalize=True)
  lf.fit(df[indep_cols.split(' ')], df[dep_col])

  return lf

df = pd.read_stata('/tmp/python.dta')
lr = linear_regression(df, 'growth', 'time time2 time3 time4 time5')

df['ghat'] = lr.predict(df['time time2 time3 time4 time5'.split(' ')])
df['resid'] = df.growth - df.ghat

df.head(5)['growth ghat resid'.split(' ')]
```

and the result is:

```
     growth      ghat     resid
0  2.352703  3.026936 -0.674233
1  2.377728  2.928860 -0.551132
2  2.354796  2.833610 -0.478815
3  3.002749  2.741135  0.261614
4  3.024933  2.651381  0.373551
```

I also tried in R, and got the same result as in Python. I could not figure out the root cause: is it because the algorithm used in Stata is a little bit different? I can tell from the source code that sklearn uses the ordinary least squares, but have no idea about the one in Stata.

Could anyone advise here?

**---------- Edit 1 -----------**

I tried to specify the data type in Stata as `double`, but Stata is still producing the same result as using `float`. The Stata codes for generating are as below:

```
gen double growth = .
foreach lag in `lags' {
    replace growth = ma_${metric}_per_`group' / l`lag'.ma_${metric}_per_`group' - 1 if nlag == `lag' & in_sample
}

gen double time = day - td(01jan2010) + 1
forvalues i = 2/5 {
    gen double time`i' = time^`i'
}
```

**---------- Edit 2 -----------**

It's confirmed that Stata does drop the `time` variable due to collinearity. The message was not seen before as our Stata codes enable the `quiet` model to suppress undesired messages. This cannot be disabled in Stata per my investigation. So it appears that I need to detect collinearity and remove collinear column(s) in Python as well.

```
. reg growth time*,
note: time omitted because of collinearity

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =     381
-------------+------------------------------           F(  4,   376) =  126.10
       Model |  37.6005042     4  9.40012605           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  28.0291465   376  .074545602           R-squared     =  0.5729
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.5684
       Total |  65.6296507   380  .172709607           Root MSE      =  .27303

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      growth |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        time |          0  (omitted)
       time2 |  -.0098885   .0009231   -10.71   0.000    -.0117037   -.0080734
       time3 |   .0000108   1.02e-06    10.59   0.000     8.77e-06    .0000128
       time4 |  -4.40e-09   4.20e-10   -10.47   0.000    -5.22e-09   -3.57e-09
       time5 |   6.37e-13   6.15e-14    10.35   0.000     5.16e-13    7.58e-13
       _cons |   3322.727   302.7027    10.98   0.000     2727.525     3917.93
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `quietly` (not `quite`) can be disabled just by not specifying it, as it is always at choice. This is prominently documented e.g. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?quietly. Is there any new question in your latest edit? There isn't really a pure programming problem here so far as I can see. Faced with a numerically tricky regression problem, different software has different criteria for handling collinearity. This may be a surprise, but it's not a new discovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The predictors are the 1st ... 5th powers of `time` which varies between 1627 and 2007 (presumably a calendar year, not that it matters). Even with modern software it would have been prudent to shift the origin of time to reduce the numerical strain, e.g. to work with powers of (`time` - 1800).

Any way, redoing the regression shows that Stata drops the first predictor as collinear. What happens in Python and R? These are different reactions to a numerically tricky challenge.

(Fitting a quintic polynomial rarely has scientific value, but that may not be of concern here. The fitted curve based on powers 2 to 5 doesn't work very well for these data, which appear economic. It makes more sense that the first 5 residuals are all positive, but that isn't true of them all!)

[image]

Comment: They're calculated as:

    for i in range(2, 6):
      df['time{0}'.format(i)] = pow(df['time'], i)


I'm using float64 for all columns. And I use to_stata to export the data to .dta file and loaded into Stata

Comment: Whatever you are doing is not enough to get accurate fifth powers. You can do the powering yourself in Stata and check. The bigger issue is the reaction to (near) collinearity. The problem is not numerically well defined.

Comment: Well, same result even if the data is generated in Stata. Here's how they're generated: forvalues i = 2/5 {
    gen time`i' = time^`i'
}

Comment: No; that generates them as `float` by default. You will get errors similar to my first comment. You must `generate` them as  `double` to get accurate answers. But as said work with powers of (`time` - 1800) for a healthier numerical result.

Comment: Tried "double" for generate in Stata, but did not see any difference. Updated this info to the question

Comment: Stata still drops one predictor even when the 5th power is correct. That's already in my answer. I've recommended twice now to shift the origin.

Comment: Do you mean changing "gen  time = day - td(01jan2010) + 1" to "gen time = day - td(01jan2010) + 1 - 1800"?

Comment: No; I said and meant subtracting 1800. (Are these daily dates? `td(1jan2010)` is 18263, which makes the times very, very different). They look like calendar years to me.

Comment: Yes, they're daily dates. Forgive me for my stupidness: isn't ""gen time = day - td(01jan2010) + 1 - 1800" doing the substraction? Thanks!

Comment: Daily dates with what origin? Regardless of that, 1800 is roughly in the middle of the range, and that is the kind of number you should be subtracting. Introducing a shift of the order of 20000 will make the problem much, much worse!

Comment: Origin is td(01jan2010), as can be seen in the Stata codes. The latest date is always the last day of the previous month (i.e. 31jul2015 for now). In other words, I need to make the number to subtract "(td(31jul2015) - td(01jan2010)) / 2"?

Comment: Note that even `double` is not enough to hold these powers all exactly. Sorry, but I don't understand your logic on dates at all. You haven't explained what the data are or where data come from but seem to assume that we know. How does last day of the month enter into the question?  The regression only sees powers of numbers between 1627 and 2007.

Comment: Sorry! time is generated using "gen time = day - td(01jan2010) + 1", where day ranges from [dataset_date - 380, dataset_date]. dataset_date I used here is 30jun2015 (as its name indicates, it's the last day of the month when the data set was produced). 2007 = (td(30jun2015) - td(01jan2010)) + 1. Let me know if this is clear. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: That helps, thanks, but my comment still stands. You should shift your origin for the polynomial fitting to roughly the middle of the data. Even 207^5 is about 380 billion. (No more comments from me today, as its is 01:39 locally.)

Comment: I really appreciate your help and time! Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

It is a wild card issue. In your `Stata` code `time*` will match `time2, time3...` but not `time`. If the `Python` code is changed to `lr = linear_regression(df, 'growth', 'time2 time3 time4 time5')` it will crank out the exact same result.

## Edit

Appears `Stata` dropped the 1st independent variable. The fit can be visualized as follows:

```
lr1 = linear_regression(df, 'growth', 'time time2 time3 time4 time5')
lr2 = linear_regression(df, 'growth', 'time2 time3 time4 time5')
pred_x1 = ((np.linspace(1620, 2000)[..., np.newaxis]**np.array([1,2,3,4,5]))*lr1.coef_).sum(1)+lr1.intercept_
pred_x2 = ((np.linspace(1620, 2000)[..., np.newaxis]**np.array([2,3,4,5]))*lr2.coef_).sum(1)+lr2.intercept_
plt.plot(np.linspace(1620, 2000), pred_x1, label='Python/R fit')
plt.plot(np.linspace(1620, 2000), pred_x2, label='Stata fit')
plt.plot(df.time, df.growth, '+', label='Data')
plt.legend(loc=0)
```

[image]

And the residual sum of squares:

```
In [149]:

pred1 = (df.time.values[..., np.newaxis]**np.array([1,2,3,4,5])*lr1.coef_).sum(1)+lr1.intercept_
pred2 = (df.time.values[..., np.newaxis]**np.array([2,3,4,5])*lr2.coef_).sum(1)+lr2.intercept_
print 'Python fit RSS',((pred1 - df.growth.values)**2).sum()
print 'Stata fit RSS',((pred2 - df.growth.values)**2).sum()
Python fit RSS 7.2062436549
Stata fit RSS 28.0291464826
```

Comment: @DSM, I found it strange. Shouldn't `*` match 0 or any number of characters? `?` would just match 1 and only 1 character. Don't have access to `Stata`  can't test.

Comment: I tried "list time*" in Stata, and it list "time time2 time3 time4 time5". But it's weird, if I update the Python codes not to include "time", the result is identical...

Comment: Using another input data set, it's completely different: including "time" produces the same result, while excluding produces a different one. So I'm guessing if Stata discards "time" in the first data set by running some criteria.

Comment: No; the first part of this is incorrect. in Stata `time*` matches `time` as well. But by accident I think you hit on the real issue, which is that Stata drops `time` as collinear with the other predictors.

Comment: @NickCox I've the same guess. Is there a way in Python to test collinear?

Comment: You can get the correlation matrix by `print df['time time2 time3 time4 time5'.split(' ')].corr()`.  Does sound tricky that `Stata` will drop a independent variable silently, not the best approach IMO.

Comment: Stata makes it totally explicit that the predictor is `drop`ped, which is how I know. I have never used Python and can't comment further on what it can do.

Comment: The statement about wildcards in Stata remains incorrect.